# How to solve this integral analytically or numerically?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2}-\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{2}\right)\log\left(e^{-x x_0}+e^{x x_0}+2\cos(x_0(y+y_0))\right) \mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$

where the  parameters $x_0$ and $y_0$ are positive real numbers.

```
p0 = 2

fct = Exp[-(1/2)*(x - x0)^2 - (1/2)*(y - y0)^2] * Log[Exp[-x*x0] + 
  Exp[x*x0] + 2*Cos[x0*(y + y0)]]

intfct = Integrate[fct, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> x0 >= 0]
```

Is there any way to solve the integral analytically or numerically?

Comment: To enable people to copy and paste, enter your code in code blocks rather than TeX or images of expressions. See [`How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site`](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/9362)

Comment: @user448659, if this is your question, please go [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged.

Comment: The second term in your integrand seems to be causing the difficulty. If I look at With[{x0=6, y0=2}, Plot3D[Log[Exp[-x x0]+Exp[x x0]+2 Cos[x0 (y+y0)]], {x,-8,8}, {y,-4,4}]] it seems your second term might be close to a constant times x (must make this work for + and - x without introducing ABS). Then Integrate[Exp[-(x+x0)^2/2 - (y-y0)^2/2] 5 Sqrt[x^2], {x,-Infinity,Infinity}, {y,-Infinity,Infinity}] quickly gives a result. BUT you have to determine whether this is a good enough approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the $\log$ term, I doubt that there is any tractable analytic solution. However, numerical integration is immediate:

```
int[a_, b_][x_, y_] := Exp[-(1/2)(x + a)^2 - (1/2)(y - b)^2] *
  Log[E^(-a x) + E^(a x) + 2 Cos[a (y + b)]]

nint[a_, b_] := NIntegrate[
  int[a, b][x, y], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

E.g. try `nint[1,2]`.

One useful transformation for (doubly-)infinite integrals, especially those involving Gaussian functions, is to observe that the integral must be *invariant* under linear transformation of each variable, e.g. $x\to x-a$ and $y\to y+b$. Applying this transformation to the integrand,

```
int[a, b][x - a, y + b] // FullSimplify
```

yields a (somewhat) simplified expression.

One sees that this integral is *independent* of $b$ for $a=0$ and evaluates to $\pi  \log (16)$.

Also, because the transformed integral involves $\cos (a (2 b+y))$—and this is the *only* place that $b$ appears in the integrand—the integral has to be *periodic* in $b$ with period $\frac{\pi }{a}$.